# Missing header files when trying to build Skia

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, build, skia

I'm trying to use the [Skia](https://skia.org/user/download) graphics library on Windows which requires [building it from source](https://skia.org/user/build). However, when I run the build command:

```
ninja -C out/Static
```

I get this build error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOMINMAX -DNDEBUG -DSK_GAMMA_APPLY_TO_A8 -DSKIA_IMPLEMENTATION=1 -DSK_HAS_PNG_LIBRARY "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/include" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/winrt" -I../.. /bigobj /utf-8 /O2 /Zc:inline  /GR- /c ../../src/codec/SkPngCodec.cpp /Foobj/src/codec/png.SkPngCodec.obj /Fd"obj/png_c.pdb"
path\to\skia\src\codec\SkPngCodec.cpp(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'png.h': No such file or directory
```

I tried running it again and now I get a different error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC -DSK_PDF_USE_SFNTLY -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOMINMAX -DNDEBUG -DSK_GAMMA_APPLY_TO_A8 -DSKIA_IMPLEMENTATION=1 -DSK_SUPPORT_PDF -DSK_HAS_JPEG_LIBRARY -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/include" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um" "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/winrt" -I../.. -I../../third_party/externals/sfntly/cpp/src /bigobj /utf-8 /O2 /Zc:inline  /GR- /c ../../src/pdf/SkDeflate.cpp /Foobj/src/pdf/pdf.SkDeflate.obj /Fd"obj/pdf_c.pdb"
C:\Users\natan\Desktop\skia\src\pdf\SkDeflate.cpp(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory
```

How do I obtain all these missing files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered [on the Skia google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/skia-discuss/NU88nZ3F9Z8/8Lcc6RQ1BwAJ), if you are missing some libraries, you need to disable the parts that depend on the missing libraries by passing `skia_use_foo=false` while generating the build files like this:

```
"bin/gn.exe" gen out/Static --args="is_official_build=true skia_use_libpng=false skia_use_zlib = false skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_harfbuzz=false skia_use_libwebp=false skia_use_expat=false"
```

Then build normally using

```
ninja -C out/Static
```

If you are missing additional libraries find out the syntax to disable them by using

```
gn args --list out/Static
```

(If you don't know what library a header file belongs to a google search will help too)

Answer (score 5):

A few years have passed, maybe the situation has changed, and there are different practices in the official documentation.
First you should run `python tools/git-sync-deps` to download all dependencies.
Then, if you find that there are still header files that cannot be found during compilation, add the `skia_use_system_xxx=false` parameter.
Here's the command I use on Windows:

```bash
bin/gn gen out/Static --args='is_official_build=true skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_system_harfbuzz=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_icu=false'
ninja -C out/Static
```

In this way, you can still compile all dependencies. The only change is that the dependencies are obtained from the place you just downloaded instead of the system path.

Comment: Thank you for the tip; it saved me a lot of time. The only addition I did was also `skia_use_system_freetype2=false`